# Code alignment lines?

Tags: aptana, aptana3

Does Aptana Studio 3 have the ability to show vertical lines that match the opening and ending tags so that you know that the tags are correctly aligned? I have found this very useful in Notepad++ and was wondering if this was an option in Aptana.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did this worked on Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.4.1.201306062137 ?

Comment: Yes, it works on my Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.4.2.201308081805

Comment: I just seen this. I was not installing it correctly. It work like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

For code alignment click in:
Source > Format